# What's wrong with my code to read and replace python text file line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have a text file. I would like to use python v3.6 to read the text file line by line, append each line with a sub-string and replace the existing line with the appended string line by line.

To be clearer, here is the original text file;

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The desired output text file should look like this;

```
appended_text,1,2,3
appended_text,4,5,6
```

This is how my code looks like;

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        newline = "appended_text" + "," + line            
        myfile.write(newline)
```

I did not get what I want. What I got instead was a huge line of text appended at the end of the file. How should the code be modified? Is there a better way to implement what I want?

Comment: Thank you @SiHa for finding the duplicate question.

Comment: PS. The best solution is probably the `fileinput` module, see the *second* answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as "replacing an existing line" in a file. For what you want to do, you have to write a new file with the modified content and then replace the old file with the new one. Example code:

```
with open("old.file") as old, open("new.file", "w") as new:
    for line in old:        
        line = modify(line.lstrip())
        new.write(line + "\n")
os.rename("new.file", "old.file")
```

Comment: @chepner thx for the s/move/rename/ fix ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, in general, modify a file in place like this. Instead, write a copy to a new file, then replace the original with the new one.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    with open("copy", 'w') as newfile:
        for line in myfile:
            newline = "appended_text" + "," + line            
            newfile.write(newline)

os.rename("copy", filename)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer actually.

Comment: Eh, we have essentially the same answer. What the user does to `newline` before writing it isn't terribly important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append("appended_text" + "," + line)
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

For example:

**sample.txt before**:

```
hello
there
world
```

**code:**

```
fp = r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\sample.txt"
with open(fp, 'r+') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append("something," + line)
        lines.append(line.strip() + ",something\n")
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

**sample.txt after:**

```
something,hello
hello,something
something,there
there,something
something,world
world,something
```

A couple of notes:

1. This assumes you are going to append to the front of each line. Thus the newline (`'\n'`) is kept with the original content of each line. If you are appending to the end, I would change to: `lines.append(line.strip() + "," + "appended_text")`.
2. You can probably combine `"appended_text"` and the `","` to `"appended_text,"`. Unless `"appended_text"` is a varable like `appended_text = "something"`.
3. Though contextually correct as a solution to your question; I'd look to writing a new file with the changes desired and replacing the old one with the new one as recommend in other answers.

Comment: This isn't safe. If there is an error during one of the writes, you could wind up with a corrupted file. It's better to ensure the *entire* file can be written safely first, then replace the old file with the new in one atomic move.

Comment: @chepner What error would one encounter? Iterating and storing values in a container, seeking and overwriting is no different than opening the same file after a read and truncating with the `'w'` mode.

Comment: That's right; they are *both* unsafe. IO errors are almost by definition unpredictable; you don't want to risk overwriting the original file until the new file is *completely* written.

Comment: @chepner Fair point. I'll leave the answer since it is contextually correct as a solution to the posed question. Though I've updated it to make note.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write it to the same file:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

lines = ['appended_text, ' + l for l in lines]

f = open(filename, 'w')
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

Comment: This is essentially the same thing bruno desthuilltiers and I are doing, but at the added expense of reading the entire original file into memory first.

Comment: (And you risk partially overwriting the original file in the event of any write errors.)

Comment: @MrPyCharm Try running this on a 100Go file ;)

Answer (score -1):

I believe to get what you want you need to put `myfile.readlines()` before your `for` loop.

Comment: Have you tried your "solution" ?

Comment: Yes I have. In fact, Kleo G has confirmed my answer in a clearer fashion above.

Comment: He confirmed nothing. The op is reading the file line by line.